# Does it make sense to upgrade my set up to 4K from a (Canon) 70D set up?

Tags: video-recording, canon, 4k

I'm not very experienced, but I keep hearing, "it's a good time to upgrade to a 4K setup".

This is quite expensive, especially at this stage, but does it make sense from a logistical point of view? I would like to be doing this for quite sometime, but the 70D purchase set me back quite a bit.

Comment: Depends entirely on what you are doing with it. IMHO, the Canon EOS 70D is an excellent camera which produces a great image, and Full HD is totally sufficient for most video projects. Unless you absolutely need 4K for some reason, there is no reason to upgrade. But then again, depends on what you are using it for ...

Comment: No explicit need. Just a concept, of "future-proofing".

Comment: Welll you are using your camera for something. If you don't use it at all, you don't need one °A°

Comment: That is indeed true. Could you recommend some not to expensive lenses?

Comment: Also, the 70D ist primarily a photo camera imo, even though it shoots great videos as well. Are you using it to take pictures or shoot video primarily?
The lenses question also depends on what you are doing. Portaits, landscapes, architecture ... ?

Comment: Video lenses, I'm currently using a standard canon prime lens. I'm hopeful that that is good enough.

Comment: Hm that is also an entirely different matter than your original question ... again, without knowing what you are shooting or what look you are going for, one can only give a very generic answer (also I myself don't have a lot of experience shooting video with different lenses, I've mostly used the generic 18-135mm lense that comes with the EOS 70D which is a great allrounder imo). That is, in addition to this standard lense get some prime lenses, like a 50mm ... honestly given that little information, the best answer I can give is to google 'good video lenses' and read up on the topic ...

Comment: [Here](http://www.omnicoreagency.com/best-dslr-lens-for-video-shooting-canon-2015/) is an article on that topic and [here](http://www.starkinsider.com/2014/05/best-lenses-shooting-video-canon-dslr.html) is another one

Comment: I just remembered that the 70D does not necessarily come with the 18-135mm zoom lense. If you only have a prime lense, get that zoom lense, as I said it's a good allrounder

Comment: I have a 55 - 250mm zoom.

Comment: Wel that should suffice for most applications. Maybe get a prime lense for wide angles, something like 24mm or 35mm ... but again, depends on what you are shooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all boils down to "Do you need it"

If you are shooting corp promos and your clients keep asking or are insisting on 4K then Yes you can look into it as you can justify the purchase as the work is going to pay for it in the end.

If it is just an odd job here and there that they want 4K then hire one as it will be much cheaper at £££/$$$ for a day or two compared to £££££/$$$$$ plus upgrading cards and all your other kit to compliment the new camera.

I had the same thought but only upgraded to a Canon C100 from my Canon 7D and didnt have to upgrade much else but did get rid of a few obstacles as well.

Put the money back into some decent glass and or upgrade other elements which could make your productions better, ie Audio, Lighting, Tripods, Lenses etc camera bodies you can swap and change but good accessories will last the test of time.

Comment: Indeed that makes sense.

Comment: @EricERK Glad it makes sense, I tried to write it to be simple and clear, 4K is great if its going to be seen in 4K or you want a bit of wiggle room with adjusting shots or even loads of VFX but your average joe wont know the diff between 1080, 4K, 6K